# 600K APIs calls daily and generate file

Tags: rest, process

I have a requirement to make 600K API calls daily for 300k users (calling two APIs per user) to fetch basic and complete details. Additionally, I need to generate a file. I’m seeking suggestions on the tools or tech that supports fast execution using different threads, ensuring it doesn’t take hours, and come with monitoring for exceptions. Your insights are appreciated.